# Not able to get photo using Microsoft graph API

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

We are integrating Microsoft Azure AD with our application. I am trying to get user profile pic using Microsoft Graph API (https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id | userPrincipalName}/photo/$value) . But its not working for me. I have given all permission required for this API in application but every time getting below response. Can you please let me what configuration I missed.

Response:

```
{

    "error": {

        "code": "ResourceNotFound",

        "message": "Resource could not be discovered.",

        "innerError": {

            "request-id": "dc27c602-5734-4dec-9b2a-8b42d5577073",

            "date": "2019-07-02T10:33:42"

        }

    }

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reading and updating a user's profile photo is only possible if the user has a mailbox. Additionally, any photos that may have been previously stored using the thumbnailPhoto property (using the Office 365 unified API preview, or the Azure AD Graph, or through AD Connect synchronization) are no longer accessible through the Microsoft Graph photo property of the user resource. For more details You could check [official docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/known-issues#photo-restrictions)

> Microsoft Graph v1.0 retrieves the user's profilePhoto from Exchange
>   Online, not Azure Active Directory. As such, users that don't have a
>   mailbox provisioned in Exchange Online will not have a profilePhoto
>   available

**Your Case:**

You could try with `Microsoft Graph REST API Beta` version request URL in flowing format:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/UserIdOrPrincipalName/photo/$value
```

See the screen shot below:

**Azure Active Directory Profile Picture:**

[image]

**Post Man Request Example:**

**Request URL:**

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/UserIdOrPrincipalName/photo/$value
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

**Points To Remember:**

> Make sure you have upload user photo in azure portal profile.

**Note:**

> APIs under the /beta version in Microsoft Graph are subject to change.
>   Use of these APIs in production applications is not supported

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Do you know when will be this API version available for production.

Comment: It is on continuous enhancement hope it will release end of this year but you can still use it.  We will be update you [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/updates/)

Comment: Keep an eye on our change log for Microsoft Graph actually https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/changelog

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron Your suggestion for using Microsoft Graph REST API Beta version request URL (shown in your response above) worked great for me (Thank you).

Comment: @nam My pleasure ^^