# Retrieve Profile picture information using Azure Graph API

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to use Microsoft graph [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/profilephoto-get?view=graph-rest-1.0) to retrieve the Profile pic from Azure Active directory.

I have used below URL and I am able to get the response successfully.
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/myemailid@myorg.com

With the same code I am getting below JSON error when i use below URL to fetch the profile photo information.
URL i used:
https://graph.microsoft.com/users/myemailid@myorg.com/photo/$value

Error JSON i got:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "OrganizationFromTenantGuidNotFound",
    "message": "The tenant for tenant guid '<<My Tenant GUID>>' does not exist.",
    "innerError": {
      "requestId": "a3f7202f-b2c0-47d4-a04d-4b642c6f4188",
      "date": "2019-07-17T06:33:46",
      "request-id": "a3f7202f-b2c0-47d4-a04d-4b642c6f4188"
    }
  }
}
```

Could any please help me on this. Thank you.

**Update:** My App permission in the portal [image: My App permission in the portal]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This URL(https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) helped me to find the exact answer. My issue is due to the tenant I am using, I tried same code in my Prod tenant and everything working good.

API i used is https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/username/photo/$value. No need to use the beta version. Now V1.0 has profile pic inforamtion of AAD.

Comment: When you had asked this question for V1.0 it wasn't supported. We recently made it workable. Anyway, thanks for your answer also.

Answer (score 2):

The all available formats of this API are listed on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/profilephoto-get?view=graph-rest-1.0#get-the-photo. I doubt there is a format like the one you are referring `"https://graph.microsoft.com/microsoft.com/users/myemailid@myorg.com/photo/$value"`

**Note:** You could use `Microsoft Graph API beta` version to get user profile picture. Its very simple and straight forward. You could try below API:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/UserIdOrPrincipalName/photo/$value
```

See the screen shot below:

[image]

**Permission Required:**

**Step: 1**

[image]

**Step: 2**

[image]

**Step: 3**

[image]
For details you could refer [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56851425/not-able-to-get-photo-using-microsoft-graph-api/56854869#56854869)

Comment: I have wrongly wrote "https://graph.microsoft.com/microsoft.com/users/myemailid@myorg.com/photo/$value" actualy I am using "https://graph.microsoft.com//users/myemailid@myorg.com/photo/$value". Now i edited the question with correct URL

Comment: @Avinash Use this URL `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/UserIdOrPrincipalName/photo/$value` For details follow the my answer.

Comment: I used beta url also but getting same error for https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/UserIdOrPrincipalName/photo/$value but working fine for https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/UserIdOrPrincipalName.

Comment: So the problem resolved? this is the correct format 
 `https://graph.microsoft.com/V1.0/users/orgEmail@YourTenant.onmicrosoft.com/photo/$value`. Your  this link `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/UserIdOrPrincipalName` is for getting user information not profile picture. your question was for photo

Comment: No the problem was not resolved. I used beta and v1.0 but both the URLs are giving same error.

Comment: I used url https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/testuser1@testorg1.onmicrosoft.com/photo/$value. But getting UnAuthorized exception status code with error message as mentioned in the question

Comment: Does your token has permission for this operation? You need `User.Read.All` permission

Comment: I updated my question with permission i have. Could you please check.

Comment: Make you have write correct tenant name. Your error message shows you are trying with wrong tenant which doesn't exist. By the way have `grant your consent` that I specified on step 3

Comment: Debug your token here  `https://jwt.io/` make sure `Token Endpoint`, `Tenant` and `Access Token` are correct.