# How to get user image in Microsoft Graph using python

Tags: python, microsoft-graph-api

I tried using `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo/$value` to get the user's image/photo but it only returns an `HTTP 200` status code. How can I get the binary data?

```
graph_url = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0'

def get_user(token):
  graph_client = OAuth2Session(token=token)
  # Send GET to /me
  user = graph_client.get('{0}/me'.format(graph_url))
  # Return the JSON result*
  return user.json()


def get_image(token):
  graph_client = OAuth2Session(token=token)
  # Send GET to /me
  image = graph_client.get('{0}/me/photo/$value'.format(graph_url))

  print('image_graph',image)
  return image
```

I'm expecting to receive a binary data

Comment: What have you checked to say the response doesn't contain the image? 200 is ok so I would say it should contain it.

Comment: I tried to print on the console and this is the result "image_graph <Response [200]>"

Comment: That's only the string representation of the returned object (`Response`). I don't know the library you are using but check the documentation to see how to get the data from the Response object.

Comment: Visit it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56851425/not-able-to-get-photo-using-microsoft-graph-api

Comment: What are you expecting `image` to be here? `$value` is going to return the RAW binary content, it isn't an encoded value or URL.

Answer (score 1):

Since `OAuth2Session.get` method returns `Response` object, you could access response body as bytes via [`Content` property](https://requests.kennethreitz.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#binary-response-content).

The following example demonstrates how to download a profile photo and save to local file:

```
graph_client = OAuth2Session(token=token)
resp = graph_client.get('{0}/me/photo/$value'.format(graph_url))
if resp.status_code == 200:
    with open(path, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(resp.content)
```