# MS Graph v1.0 Profile Picture Ressource Not Found

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I tried to do the Learning Path on Microsoft. But at **Build apps with Microsoft Graph – Associate** under **Access User Data from Microsoft Graph** in **Unit 4 of 8** I've get an **"Ressource not found"** Error. If I try to catch my profile picture in the graph explorer I get an Ressource not found Error too, but under "Beta" it displays my picture. I think this Learn Path is outdated.

My Question is, how can I change the code given in the Learning Path to speaks to the BETA and not v1.0.

```
var resultsUserPhoto = requestUserPhoto.GetAsync().Result;
```

This line makes the problem.

Greetings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have understood that you are using the Microsoft Graph V1.0 SDK. To hit the beta endpoint for only 1 request you can modify the BaseUrl to graph client and make a beta request.

```
graphClient.BaseUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta";
var pictureStream = await graphClient.Me.Photo.Content.Request().GetAsync();
```

For further referrence see this [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56851425/not-able-to-get-photo-using-microsoft-graph-api).

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me with both **v1.0** and **beta** but only if I really have profile photo:

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );    
var stream = await graphClient.Me.Photo.Content
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();
```

For profile without photo it returns `Resource not found`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! 
So instead of changing the complete code from v1.0 to BETA I need to change the 404 error when I'm trying to get a photo. 

Any ideas why its only when I'm using v1.0 ?